# std::cout, ostream and other kinds of getting output stream

Tags: c++, std, iostream

In my project (Unreal Engine 4) I don't have an output stream - instead of this I can communicate via UE_LOG function, which works pretty much similar to `printf()`. The problem is that I just made a .dll library (without Unreal includes) which I want to communicate through the `iostream`. My idea is - inside .dll library I use standard `cout` to write messages into ostream, I use all of it in Unreal Engine functions, where I grab `ostream` in form of string and output it into UE_LOG function.

Problem is I always treated `std::cout` as a part of magic, without thinking what is really inside (I am pretty sure most of us did). How I can handle this? Easy ways won't work (like grabbing `stringstream` and outputing it into UE_LOG).

Comment: Wrap that stuff to match the `std::ostream` syntax. BIG GRIN :D

Comment: Why pass streams around when you can just pass strings? Have the functions in the DLL take `std::string` arguments, and if they need to return a string then return a `std::string`.

Comment: @joachim-pileborg Yes, but dll function can make complicated process and it would have to call before and after execution - so just grabbing the string won't help.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand exactly what you want, but did you check [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/basic_ostringstream)?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yo, the last line is about that. Or maybe I don't know some hidden function, like real-time update or smth.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice. What was the problem with it? Do your library uses `cout` extensively, so you cannot replace it with other stream object?

Comment: Well, I can pass stringstream pointer to function, I wanted something more smooth - you have only one ostream pointer (I think, I don't know - as I was trying with console, dll can write on cout to console). If changing cout is so hard I can consider stringstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My idea is - inside .dll library I use standard cout to write messages into ostream

You actually can replace the output buffer used with `std::cout` with your own implementation. Use the [`std::ostream::rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) function to do so (example from the reference docs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream local;
    auto cout_buff = std::cout.rdbuf(); // save pointer to std::cout buffer

    std::cout.rdbuf(local.rdbuf()); // substitute internal std::cout buffer with
        // buffer of 'local' object

    // now std::cout work with 'local' buffer
    // you don't see this message
    std::cout << "some message";

    // go back to old buffer
    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);

    // you will see this message
    std::cout << "back to default buffer\n";

    // print 'local' content
    std::cout << "local content: " << local.str() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to make local.rdbuf. Remember, I have function with form of printf. Only things I can pass there are c_strings, integers and so on.

Comment: Idea is very good, but only one thing I need to go is to overload std::ostringstream::flush function (or something else rensponsible to flush things on terminal) to automatically write things into my Output Console (you know, UE_LOG which works like printf).

Comment: @CheshireCat _"one thing I need to go is to overload `std::ostringstream::flush` function"_ If you're overloading from your own implementation I think [`std::basic_streambuf::sync()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsync) will be responsible to do that.

Comment: Well it's better than nothing, but it still doesn't give me a way to get update in real time. I'll look for something similar, maybe inheriting from class. Still +1 for giving me hint with rdbuf :)

Answer (score 0):

(in case my edit won't be positively reviewed)

From OP: Thanks to your hints I finally found how to solve my problem. Suppose I want to get stream from cout and send it to printf (because I think stdio library is superior to iostream). Here how I can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class ssbuf : public stringbuf{
protected:
    int sync(){
        printf("My buffer: %s",this->str().c_str());
        str("");
        return this->stringbuf::sync();
    }
};


int main(){
    ssbuf *buf = new ssbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(buf);
    cout<<"This is out stream "<<"and you cant do anything about it"<<endl;
    cout<<"(don't) "<<"Vote Trump"<<endl;
}
```

Code is very raw, but it does it's job. I made child class of buffer which has method sync() downcasting original virtual method sync(). Except this it works like usual buffer, just grabs all console-out stream - exactly what we wanted. The str("") inside is to clean the buffer - probably not outputted stream doesn't clean itself.

Great thanks for help! Big GRIN for you! :D